# How to validate in Strapi (typescript) before creating one content that combined key is unique?

Tags: strapi

I am using `"@strapi/strapi": "^4.12.5",` and have to say that this is one amazing open-source CMS.

There are things missing, like the one I need help with and will explain below.

I have the following content-type named `Block` with the schema as below

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "blocks",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "block",
    "pluralName": "blocks",
    "displayName": "Block"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {
    "i18n": {
      "localized": true
    }
  },
  "attributes": {
    "container": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": false
        }
      },
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 512,
      "required": true,
      "unique": false
    },
    "key": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": false
        }
      },
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 512,
      "required": true
    },
    "sections": {
      "pluginOptions": {
        "i18n": {
          "localized": true
        }
      },
      "type": "dynamiczone",
      "components": [
        "sections.rich-text"
      ],
      "required": true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that the combination of `container`-`key`-`locale` cannot be present 2 times, so that combination is unique.

**Example of the desired functionality:**

1. user inserts for locale en container=home, key=footer, anyOtherDataDoesntMatter
2. user tries to insert again for locale en, container=home, key=footer, whateverRestOfData. This operation should fail with proper validation error that "container-key-locale" is unique.

This is the default generated `src/api/block/controllers/block.ts` controller

```
/**
 * block controller
 */

import { factories } from '@strapi/strapi';

export default factories.createCoreController('api::block.block');
```

What is the best approach to add this validation logic and show a meaningful message to the admin UI ?

With the code and schema that I shared there is no validation in place and the content editor can add duplicate configs like the one I want to avoid.

PS: Strapi does not allow combinated keys or `unique key per locale` yet out of the box via the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for.

I used `lifecycles.ts` to hook into the `beforeCreate` and `beforeUpdate` event of my content type.
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/models#lifecycle-hooks

I did this by creating `src/api/block/content-types/block/lifecycles.ts` with the following code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { YupValidationError } from '@strapi/utils/dist/errors';
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { ValidationError } from 'yup';

const resourceType = 'api::block.block';

type Data = { locale: string; container: string; key: string };

export default {
    async beforeCreate(event) {
        const { data } = event.params;

        const existing = await getExisting(data);
        if (existing) {
            throwDuplicateCombinedKeyValidationError();
        }
    },

    async beforeUpdate(event) {
        const id = event.params.where.id;

        const { data } = event.params;
        // Strapi has a bug that does not send the locale during update so we have to fetch the existing entry and see its locale
        // only the updated values are sent into data, we have to merge with existing actual ones
        const actual = await getById(id);

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        const existingWithCombinedKey = await getExisting({
            locale: actual.locale,
            container: data.container ?? actual.container,
            key: data.key ?? actual.key,
        });

        if (existingWithCombinedKey !== null && existingWithCombinedKey.id !== id) {
            throwDuplicateCombinedKeyValidationError();
        }
    },
};

async function getById(id: number): Promise<Data | null> {
    // @ts-ignore
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const block = await strapi.service(resourceType).findOne(id);

    if (block === null) {
        return null;
    }

    return block;
}

function throwDuplicateCombinedKeyValidationError(): void {
    const errorMessage: ValidationError = {
        inner: [
            {
                name: 'ValidationError', // Always set to ValidationError
                path: 'container', // Name of field we want to show input validation on
                message: 'duplicate', // Input validation message
            },
            {
                name: 'ValidationError', // Always set to ValidationError
                path: 'key', // Name of field we want to show input validation on
                message: 'duplicate', // Input validation message
            },
        ],
    } as ValidationError;

    throw new YupValidationError(errorMessage, 'Duplicate combined key container-key-locale error');
}

async function getExisting(data: Data): Promise<{ id: number } | null> {
    // @ts-ignore
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    return await strapi.db
        .query(resourceType)
        .findOne({ where: { container: data.container, key: data.key, locale: data.locale } });
}
```

Throwing the `YupValidationError` error is supported by the frontend as well and you can achieve my 2nd goal of showing proper message to the content editor user:

[image]

I want to thank the Strapi team for the great product and also suggest that they extend the `Typescript` types for the events for easier development time.

`event` has no type in Strapi atm, also the global `strapi` does not work.